# Create a Microsoft Word Quick Style for a Code Snippet Box

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

I'm trying to format some text in my Word doc to have a background color of gray. This is for me to have a Quick Style to apply this formatting. I want to use a monospaced font, like Consolas, and have the entire block have a gray background. When I highlight text and set the background color though, it only set the color behind the text, not the area rectangular area the text sits on within the doc layout. How can I do this?

Comment: Just a quick correction - Consolas is a sans type font, not serif.

Comment: You're right! I meant monospaced, which is the key to good code snippets. Thanks, I've updated it.

Comment: Technically, monospace and sans/serif are two different properties of a font. For instance, Consolas is monospace sans, while Courier New is monospace serif. But yes, monospace is the way to go for code snippets.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've figured out how to do this:

1. Highlight arbitrary text in the document
2. In the **Styles** chunk of the ribbon, **Save Selection as new Quick Style...**
3. In the **Modify Style** dialog, click **Format** at the bottom.
4. Select **Frame**
5. Set **Text Wrapping** to **Around**
6. Click **OK**, then in the **Format** menu select **Border**
7. In the **Shading** tab, pick a **Fill** with the background color, e.g. gray

Answer (score 4):

For Office 2007 and 2010, you'll want to use the Shading tool:

[image]

That should do what you want.

I don't have an older version of Office handy to check, but you'll probably find the same tool under Format -> Paragraph, or similar menu option.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't make it into a box around the text itself. Sorry if my question wasn't clear though. I've written my solution I found. Thanks again

Comment: fastest option.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a simpler way to do this. Step by step:

1. Copy the code which you want to paste into a Word document.
2. Open the link http://hilite.me
3. Paste your code into the left side box and select the appropriate
   language from the drop-down menu. Then click the “highlight” button.
4. Copy your code from the preview section and open your Word document.
5. Insert a table of 1×1 size and paste your code there. 
   Style it according to your choice.

If something is still unclear, please have a look at [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/W7CdXThF9OQ).

Answer (score 2):

From Office 2013 there is a new quick style called 'Code'. You can disable spell-check by

**`Format->Language->Disable automatic spell-checking.`**

Comment: cannot see this style in latest version of word. even when going to manage styles > recommended, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Select the block where you want to fill the background with color, on the home section of microsoft word, above paragraph, the section where you will find the bullets & numbering there is a bucket like paint icon called the shading click the down arrow next to that icon and select any color you want to use for the background then voila!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy method that I used.
There is an office add-on https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-US/product/office/WA104382008
after installing code formatter addon to MS word from microsoft office site.
you just need to select the text and hit the code format button on word

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts here. Links can go bad after a while. Could you explain a bit further?